# Wireless stalling: TXQ MAX DEPTH?

Tags: macos, wifi, network

Got a brand new iMac 27" Mid 2011 - Core i5 and when backing up data from old iMac, through the wireless, the network stall and then stops, after some minutes it restart.

Got this problem several times, changed from DHCP to DHCP with manual address and no luck at all.

In console, shows (will list 2 logs, basicly the same, but have a lot of others):

log #1:

```
8/15/11 11:23:51.000 AM kernel: 452.012114: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:51.000 AM kernel: 452.012126: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:51.000 AM kernel: 452.215613: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:51.000 AM kernel: 452.216788: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:51.000 AM kernel: 452.216793: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 452.625339: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 452.626497: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 452.626508: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 452.932507: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 452.933563: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 452.933575: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 452.982171: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
8/15/11 11:23:52.000 AM kernel: 453.217553: setDISASSOCIATE ****STA SYNC DISASSOC SUCCESS
```

log #2:

```
8/15/11 12:40:51.000 PM kernel: 5072.454012: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:51.000 PM kernel: 5072.455714: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:51.000 PM kernel: 5072.455727: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:51.000 PM kernel: 5072.658185: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:51.000 PM kernel: 5072.659343: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:51.000 PM kernel: 5072.659355: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5072.863003: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5072.864160: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5072.864171: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5073.068132: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5073.069283: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5073.069295: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5073.682531: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5073.683721: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:52.000 PM kernel: 5073.683732: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:53.000 PM kernel: 5073.887015: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:53.000 PM kernel: 5073.888171: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:53.000 PM kernel: 5073.888182: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:53.000 PM kernel: 5074.296944: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:53.000 PM kernel: 5074.298100: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:53.000 PM kernel: 5074.298112: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5074.911379: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5074.912536: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5074.912548: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5075.526138: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5075.527208: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5075.527218: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5075.730286: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5075.731441: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:54.000 PM kernel: 5075.731453: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:55.000 PM kernel: 5076.140428: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:55.000 PM kernel: 5076.141569: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:55.000 PM kernel: 5076.141575: [3] TXQ MAX DEPTH!!!
8/15/11 12:40:55.000 PM kernel: en1: BSSID changed to 90:84:0d:dd:c4:b4
8/15/11 12:40:55.000 PM kernel: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
8/15/11 12:43:30.000 PM kernel: (default pager): [KERNEL]: ps_allocate_cluster - send HI_WAT_ALERT
8/15/11 12:43:30.000 PM kernel: macx_swapon SUCCESS
```

Think that it happens only when copying large files (larger than 3.5gb)...

Any ideas?

Comment: Did the opposite: shared a folder in the new iMac and copied from the old one (i was sharing on the old one and copying from the new one) and it worked. Although it does not solve the wireless problem, solved my migration!

Comment: Wow - that's some backup on the transmit queue. It's hard to tell what's really causing the issue. I'd check if you have more than one base station with the same SSID and also launch /System/Library/CoreServices/Wi-Fi Diagnostics.app to see if it can help diagnose the issue further...

Comment: @bmike: did not know this app. I am now monitoring to see if it shows me something. The base station has a unique SSID and, to work better - I hope -, is an Apple Airport Extreme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to OS X Lion 10.7.1 solved the issue. In http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1437 it specifies "Improve the reliability of Wi-Fi connections" that may be this problem.

Anyway, working really fine now.